# Typescript - Read user input while his answer is specific

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to build a simple command-line TypeScript application, but I don't know how to do some things. I found this piece of code here, in StackOverflow:

```
import * as readline from 'readline';

let rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Is this example useful? [y/n] ', (answer) => {
  switch(answer.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'y':
      console.log('Super!');
      break;
    case 'n':
      console.log('Sorry! :(');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Invalid answer!');
  }
  rl.close();
});
```

And it works just fine. Is there any way I can loop it? What I'm actually trying to do is to fetch some questions from a MySQL database but I have no idea how to ask a question N times.
Thank you!

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: typescript is a superset of javascript. It supports the same for, foreach, while, and do-while loops that javascript does

Comment: I have some PHP experience so I tried to wrap it in a while loop but I did't work as I expected

Comment: Any ideas? I'm totally stuck... :/

Answer (score 2):

Putting the readline in a loop is not enough because the function call is asynchronous. That means Node doesn't wait until the user has entered something.  Rather the user input will trigger an event and the callback function "(answer) => {...}" will get executed.

It is important to understand that Node is asynchronous and event driven. Every synchronuous execution of a function may block the event loop and make Node unresponsive.

One possibility is recursion used in the callback. Another option is async/await which gives the code the structure of a synchronuous execution. The third possibility is to use events (which is probably the best solution) which can be seen at the bottom of the page in the node docs (https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_tiny_cli).

Probably the most simple way when starting with your code is to use a recursive function (function calls itself at the end):

```
const readline = require('readline');

let rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});


function ask() {
  rl.question('Is this example useful? [y/n/q] ', (answer) => {
    switch(answer.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'y':
      console.log('Super!');
      break;
      case 'n':
      console.log('Sorry! :(');
      break;
      case 'q':
      console.log('Bye!');
      rl.close();
      process.exit();
      default:
      console.log('Invalid answer!');
    }

    ask();
  });
}

ask();
```

Note that this is more a way to make something really simple. There are also powerful packages for things like that. For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander.

Here is the same without the recursion but with promise and async/await:

```
async function ask() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    rl.question('Is this example useful? [y/n/q] ', (answer) => {
      switch(answer.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'y':
        console.log('Super!');
        break;
        case 'n':
        console.log('Sorry! :(');
        break;
        case 'q':
        console.log('Bye!');
        rl.close();
        process.exit();
        default:
        console.log('Invalid answer!');
      }

      resolve();
    });
  });
}

async function start() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    await ask();
  }

  rl.close();
}

start();
```

This will ask five questions (i < 5) and then exit. It will also exit when the input is 'q'. You could also use while(true) instead of for(...) to run it in an infinite loop.

Comment: May be helpful to explain to OP why just putting rl.question in a while loop doesn't work (i.e. rl.question is asynchronous) so OP knows why recursion or async/await is necessary

Comment: Thank you, sir! That was exactly what I was looking for! :)